# C++: read but can't properly write .tga file

Tags: c++, tga

**SOLVED IN COMMENTS**

I'm trying to read a .tga file, extract the header and the pixel data, check some header values and then write it into a new .tga file, but it won't quite work the way I'd want it to.

```
struct TGAFILE {
    char idLength;
    char colourMapType;
    char imageType;
    short colourMapStart;
    short colourMapNumEntries;
    char bitsPerEntry;
    short xOrigin;
    short yOrigin;
    short width;
    short height;
    char bitsPerPixel;
    char* pixelData;
};

TGAFILE loadImage(const std::string& pathToImage) {
    std::ifstream image(pathToImage, std::ios::binary);
    if (!image.is_open()) {
        throw FileNotFound();
    }
    TGAFILE tgaFile;
    image.read(&tgaFile.idLength, sizeof(tgaFile.idLength));
    image.read(&tgaFile.colourMapType, sizeof(tgaFile.colourMapType));
    image.read(&tgaFile.imageType, sizeof(tgaFile.imageType));
    image.read((char*)(&tgaFile.colourMapStart), sizeof(tgaFile.colourMapStart));
    image.read((char*)(&tgaFile.colourMapNumEntries), sizeof(tgaFile.colourMapNumEntries));
    image.read(&tgaFile.bitsPerEntry, sizeof(tgaFile.bitsPerEntry));
    image.read((char*)(&tgaFile.xOrigin), sizeof(tgaFile.xOrigin));
    image.read((char*)(&tgaFile.yOrigin), sizeof(tgaFile.yOrigin));
    image.read((char*)(&tgaFile.width), sizeof(tgaFile.width));
    image.read((char*)(&tgaFile.height), sizeof(tgaFile.height));
    image.read(&tgaFile.bitsPerPixel, sizeof(tgaFile.bitsPerPixel));

    int imageDataSize = tgaFile.width * tgaFile.height * (tgaFile.bitsPerPixel / 8);

    tgaFile.pixelData = new char[imageDataSize];

    int originalPosition = (int)image.tellg();
    image.read(tgaFile.pixelData, imageDataSize);
    return tgaFile;
}
```

(checking some header values, but not changing anything)

```
void safeImage(TGAFILE tgaFile){
    std::ofstream output("output.tga", std::ios::binary);
    output.write(&tgaFile.idLength, sizeof(tgaFile.idLength));
    output.write(&tgaFile.colourMapType, sizeof(tgaFile.colourMapType));
    output.write(&tgaFile.imageType, sizeof(tgaFile.imageType));
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tgaFile.colourMapStart), sizeof(tgaFile.colourMapStart));
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tgaFile.colourMapNumEntries), sizeof(tgaFile.colourMapNumEntries));
    output.write(&tgaFile.bitsPerEntry, sizeof(tgaFile.bitsPerEntry));
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tgaFile.xOrigin), sizeof(tgaFile.xOrigin));
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tgaFile.yOrigin), sizeof(tgaFile.yOrigin));
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tgaFile.width), sizeof(tgaFile.width));
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tgaFile.height), sizeof(tgaFile.height));
    output.write(&tgaFile.bitsPerPixel, sizeof(tgaFile.bitsPerPixel));
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tgaFile.pixelData), sizeof(tgaFile.pixelData));
    output.close();
}
```

I think I've got something wrong with `output.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tgaFile.pixelData), sizeof(tgaFile.pixelData));`, but if I'm even right, I still don't know what it is.

Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Well, `reinterpret_cast` is definitely dangerous for sure

Comment: @Chipster I'm open to suggestions :D

Comment: the last write should be `output.write(tgaFile.pixelData, imageDataSize)` where you calculate imageDataSize as in the read. `sizeof(tgaFile.pixelData)` is the size of your *pointer*, so 4 or 8. And casting the address of the pointer to a different pointer is also wrong.

Comment: Not sure I could give a good suggestion, but it is certainly [possible you are doing something wrong with `reinterpret_cast`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reinterpret_cast-in-c-type-casting-operators/).

Comment: @Botje Awesome, worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. But why wouldn't `sizeof(tgaFile.pixelData)`? Shouldn't it be the same size?

Comment: @Chipster In this specific instance OP seems to be using `reinterpret_cast` correctly. I am only confused why they are using C-style casts instead of `reinterpret_cast` for the loading portion. (In this case both do the same effectively, but C style casts are considered dangerous because they can do much more).

Comment: `sizeof(tgaFile.pixelData)` = `sizeof(char*)` = 4 or 8. C++ cannot magically infer the size of the thing you're pointing at.

Comment: @Botje You should probably make an answer out of your comment.

Comment: @uneven_mark So suggest using it when reading the values not when writing them? If so, does it work like this: ` image.read(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tgaFile.yOrigin), sizeof(tgaFile.yOrigin));?

Comment: @Cpt.Crazy It should not be `const` if you want to write to it, but other than that, yes. And keep using it when writing as well!

Comment: @Botje Ah oke. Nice to know, thanks